# Cakephp: Which function parses the request information?

Tags: php, cakephp

Can someone tell me what the default functions are in cake that process the initial request and convert the request properties into a php array? I thought it might be one of the functions in libs/http_socket.php, but it doesn't appear to be the case.

Footnote: I know that one can build custom requesthandlers but that's not what I want to do at the moment. I first want to analyze the current logic that cake is using to parse the http request.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You ought to look at the Dispatcher class and Router class. Dispatcher is called from app/webroot/index.php

Comment: Thanks guys... parseParams() in dispatcher.php was what I was looking for.

Comment: @opike - No problem. You know you can give us an up vote, too.

Answer (score 3):

`request_handler.php`:

https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp/blob/master/cake/libs/controller/components/request_handler.php

Within the cakephp install directory...

```
cakephp/cakephp/blob/master/cake/libs/controller/components/request_handler.php
```

---

`dispatcher.php` (as connrs points out...):

https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp/blob/master/cake/dispatcher.php

```
cakephp/cake/dispatcher.php
```

**Dispatcher::dispatch()** - https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp/blob/master/cake/dispatcher.php#L97

**Dispatcher::__extractParams()** - https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp/blob/master/cake/dispatcher.php#L228

**Dispatcher::parseParams()** - https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp/blob/master/cake/dispatcher.php#L244

---

`router.php`:

https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp/blob/master/cake/libs/router.php

```
cakephp/cake/libs/router.php
```

**Router::connect()** - https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp/blob/master/cake/libs/router.php#L263

**Router::connectNamed()** - https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp/blob/master/cake/libs/router.php#L339

**Router::mapResources()** - https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp/blob/master/cake/libs/router.php#L404

**Router::parse()** - https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp/blob/master/cake/libs/router.php#L446

**Router::__connectDefaultRoutes()** - https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp/blob/master/cake/libs/router.php#L577

**Router::setRequestInfo()** - https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp/blob/master/cake/libs/router.php#L623

Comment: +1 for linking to every line of code that handles requests :D